# Matlab code generation of resample: the number of terms N must be constant

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I use Matlab coder to generate C code of the following function:

```
function [out] = myresample(in)
    out = resample(in,4644,1000,10);
end
```

and generate the code by `codegen myresample -args {coder.typeof(0, [1 Inf]), 0} -config cfg`, where `cfg = coder.config('lib')`, `cfg.DynamicMemoryAllocation = 'AllVariableSizeArrays'`.

But it reports the error as:

`??? The number of terms N must be constant.`

I am confused why it is wrong. Interestingly, when I change the function to

```
function [out] = myresample(in)
    out = resample(in,10,10,10);
end
```

it works.

I have found [some links](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/393916-why-can-t-i-generate-code-for-resample-in-matlab-coder) explaining how to generate code of `resample`. But it seems not work for my case.

I use Matlab 2017b.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Matlab 2017b documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/signal/ref/resample.html):

> C/C++ Code Generation: Generate C and C++ code using MATLAB® Coder™.
>   Usage notes and limitations:
>   C and C++ code generation for resample requires DSP System Toolbox™ software.
>   The upsampling and downsampling factors must be specified as constants. Expressions or variables are allowed if their values do not change.
>   **Variable-size inputs are not supported.**

Here on your code, you have `in` that is not limited in size.

in your function `myresample`, you should try to specify a limitation. Something like:

```
limited_in = in(1:128);
out = resample(limited_in,4644,1000,10);
```

So the size of the inputs of `resample` will always be constant.